# How to cleanly put HTML elements on the same line using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

My question is how to cleanly put two elements on the same line.

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/duqpn0wd/

CSS:

```
    .inline-block {
    display: inline-block;
    }
```

Wrapper:

```
    <div class="inline-block">
    </div>
```

In the fiddle you can see a text with a button underneath it but I need them to be left align and right align like so:

TEXT                                                                BUTTON

Right now using inline-block helps but I would need each element to be an inline and the line after that would also be inline so that would merge into my existing first line like so:

TEXT     BUTTON     TEXT    BUTTON

Any ideas on how to do this properly?

Comment: You put the text in `<p>`, those are block level elements. Use `<span>Alarm Horn: </span>`

Comment: this is also a good point, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `float: left;` for the `p` inside `.inline-block`:

```css
.inline-block {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
 }
 .inline-block p{
   float: left;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="collapsible">
  <h3> Alarm </h3>
  <div class="inline-block">
    <p>Alarm Horn:</p>
    <select name="flipswitch-1" id="flipswitch-1" data-role="flipswitch" data-wrapper-class="wide-flipswitch">
      <option value="off">OFF</option>
      <option value="on">ON</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="inline-block">
    <p>Alarm Light:</p>
    <select name="flipswitch-2" id="flipswitch-2" data-role="flipswitch" data-wrapper-class="wide-flipswitch">
      <option value="off">OFF</option>
      <option value="on">ON</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div data-role="collapsible">
  <h3> Fault </h3>
  <div class="inline-block">
    <label for="number-input-1">Start Fault Time:</label>
    <button id="number-input-1" class="keyboard-input" data-inline="true">100</button>
    <label for="number-input-1">seconds</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice and clean, I like the width since it makes it go to the next line. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code to your CSS

```
.inline-block > p {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your css with this

```css
.inline-block {
 display: inline-block;
}
p{
  display:inline-block;
}
select{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="collapsible">
<h3> Alarm </h3>
<div class="inline-block">
<p>Alarm Horn:</p>
<select name="flipswitch-1" id="flipswitch-1" data-role="flipswitch" data-wrapper-class="wide-flipswitch">
  <option value="off">OFF</option>
  <option value="on">ON</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="inline-block">
<p>Alarm Light:</p>
<select name="flipswitch-2" id="flipswitch-2" data-role="flipswitch" data- wrapper-class="wide-flipswitch">
<option value="off">OFF</option>
<option value="on">ON</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>

<div data-role="collapsible">
<h3> Fault </h3>
<div class="inline-block">
<label for="number-input-1">Start Fault Time:</label>
<button id="number-input-1" class="keyboard-input" data-   inline="true">100</button>
<label for="number-input-1">seconds</label>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Changing `p` like that in general is probably a bad idea.

Comment: I just shown him how he can accomplish his goal, he can add `id` to `p` and use in css.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your CSS as :

```
.inline-block { /* select the class */
display: inline-block;
}

.inline-block *{ /* select all the child element  */
 display: inline-block;
}
```

Adding any element to your class will be aligned in a single line.